# How to create a textfield that can hold multiple values eg.email to: field which contains multiple recepient email address

Tags: swift, uipickerview, textfield

I have a UITextField which has pickerview as inputview.Pickerview displays data from a string array stored in NSUSERDEFAULTS(eg.["horse","cat","camel","cow","parrot","peacock"]). I need to select multiple values from the picker and display it in a single UITextField like in email to: field.
Could you please provide some inputs to this?

Currently im able to pick one value from picker and set the textfield to that value.Need to know how to select multiple values from a single component of picker and set it to a single textfield.

PFB the code which i tried

```
class ViewController: UIViewController,UITextFieldDelegate,UIPickerViewDelegate,UIPickerViewDataSource {



    var item = String()
    var itemsaved = [String]()

    @IBOutlet var searchTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet var picker: UIPickerView!


    let itemArray = ["camel","cow","horse","duck","parrot","peacock"]
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard


    override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()
        defaults.set(itemArray, forKey: "stringArray")
        self.searchTextField.inputView = picker
        picker.removeFromSuperview()
        self.picker.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        self.searchTextField.delegate = self

        searchTextField.addTarget(self, action: #selector(ViewController.editingchanged(_:)),
                                  for: UIControl.Event.editingChanged)
    }


    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return self.itemsaved.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String? {

        return self.itemsaved[row]
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {

        self.searchTextField.text = self.itemsaved[row]
        self.view.endEditing(true)


    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }



    func retreivedata(sender:UITextField) {
        if let savedItems = defaults.stringArray(forKey: "stringArray"){
            for item in savedItems{
                item.hasPrefix(sender.text!){
                    print(item)
                    itemsaved.append(item)

                }
            }
        }
    }



    @IBAction func editingchanged(_ sender: UITextField) {
        self.picker.dataSource = self
        self.picker.delegate = self
        retreivedata(sender: self.searchTextField)
    }
}
```

Comment: SHow the code you are using. and also mention if u want to show multiple selected values in one text field or multiple textfields?

Comment: I want to show multiple selected values from the picker to one textfield.I have added the code.Thanks!

Comment: Here is an example of what you need https://github.com/akonoplev/Features/blob/master/MultiSelectUIPickerView/MultiSelectUIPickerView/ViewController.swift